Linear Mixed-effects Modelling for Mouse Tumor Growth Data
I tried going through the available materials online for this issue, but I did not manage to find many great resources. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or advice you could provide.
I have mice tumor growth volumes across time for 4 different treatment arms. I want to compare the tumor growth trajectories and show that there is a statistically significant difference between the growth curves. I believe the most appropriate way to do this is by linear mixed-effects modelling, but I’m not sure about the appropriate way to perform and interpret the results using the lme4 and lmerTest libraries in R. Take note that I have missing data for some of the samples in varying days, but I think the mixed-effects modelling should handle this.
This is how I’m doing it right now with a dataframe containing four columns (volume, day, arm, and mouse):
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
df$volume <- log(df$volume) # Converting the volumes in mm cubed to their logs
df$arm <- factor(df$arm, levels = c("A", "B", "C ", "D")) #Converting the arms to factors, with the control arm  set to the first level
mod <- lmer(volume ~ day * arm + (1+ day|mouse), data = df) # Performing the modelling
summary(mod) # Printing the results

My questions:

Is this the appropriate way to perform this analysis?
I am unsure as to how to interpret the results. Am I correct to assume that, for example, if I want to see whether tumor growth in arm B is significantly different compared to arm A, I have to look at the day:armB estimate and p-values? And that a positive estimate indicates that the increase in tumor sizes is higher in arm B and a negative estimate means the increase in tumor size is lower in arm B?
What is the appropriate way to also check whether there is a significant difference between arms C and D? Should I simply relevel the arm factor so that either C or D is the baseline and then look at the estimate/p-value for the other arm?
Finally, there seems to be a shift in tumor behaviors between arm C and arm D at the final 20% of the days in the study, where the tumors in arm C appear to became resistant to the treatment while the tumors in arm D appear to still respond. However, the differences between the two arms are not significant based on this analysis, but I believe this is due to the fact that the two arms show a completely similar trajectory in the primary part of the study (80% of days). How should I accommodate this change in behavior of tumors and appropriately compare these two arms?

Any and all help with this is really appreciated.

You might also check https://rpubs.com/bbolker/ratgrowthcurves

With respect to Question 1:
Although mixed models are frequently used, they aren't the only or necessarily the best way to handle within-individual correlations in longitudinal studies like yours. First, the lme4 package might not allow for the best correlation structure for this type of study. Second, you might be better off with a different way to handle the within-animal correlations.
First, for drug treatment studies on mouse xenografts, Zavrakidis et al.,  Statistical analysis of longitudinal data on tumour growth in mice experiments, Scientific Reports 10, Article number: 9143 (2020) evaluated several approaches and found that an AR-1 autoregressive correlation structure was typically needed to model log-transformed tumor volumes correctly over time. That structure can't be specified for mixed models with the lme4 package but it can with the nlme package. See this page.
Second, you don't need to use a mixed model to handle within-animal correlations. Zavrakidis et al. found that a classic "growth curve" analysis via generalized least squares with an AR-1 structure could be preferable, as it was more likely to converge than a corresponding mixed model. That might be because the variance of random intercepts among genetically inbred mice can be very small, leading to near-0 estimates of the random-term variance and corresponding convergence problems (or at least error messages). With generalized least squares you don't model random effects for individuals; the correlation structure handles within-individual associations. The nlme package's gls() function fits generalized least squares models with many correlation structure choices.
Frank Harrell devotes Chapter 7 of Regression Modeling Strategies primarily to generalized least squares. You will find that he recommends more flexible modeling of time than the simple linear form implicit in your model; restricted cubic splines for time interacting with treatment can be a good choice. Flexible modeling will probably help evaluate the "shift in tumor behaviors" near the end of the study that you note in Question 4. That Chapter has a worked through case study and shows how to document that you have chosen an appropriate correlation structure.
With respect to Questions 2 and 3:
Trying to work directly with reported coefficients can be difficult when interactions are involved. You need to consider all of the relevant coefficients (main and interaction coefficients) and use the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates to evaluate statistical significance. To avoid errors, it's best to use software that performs post-modeling comparisons that you specify. Frank Harrell's rms package can do that if you use its Gls() wrapper for the gls() function. The emmeans package can do post-modeling comparisons on a wide variety or models in R, including gls() models.

Agreed, see also the marginaleffects package
